# Artificial Intelligence Search

Tags: algorithm, search, mathematical-optimization

everybody. I am working on a university timetable scheduler project.  Mainly, I am using taboo search, but I want to ask:

In general search, you can explore all neighbors of the current state and then take the best state - according to a fitness or evaluation function, - but in such a project, generating all neighbors will make performance down, so is there any way that make me bypass such problem?  For example, can I generate children for only one state and then benefit from this generation for all other states during the search process?

Please, if anyone has an expert in such algorithms, please tell me, because I have worked hard on such issues.

Comment: You say that generating the neighbors leads performance issues, but you give no details on what neighborhood you try to explore. It's hard to help you optimize an algorithm that you don't give any details on.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to shoosh's comments: Are you looking for [pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruning_(algorithm))? Numerous such strategies exist including [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) one. Remember, one size does not fit all. So, you will probably have to design a heuristic to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but it's usually not hard thinking about optimization for such calculations.
It really depends on the fitness function you use. Usually, knowing the fitness of a node you can deduce the range or even just worst to best case range of fitness of the children.
With a simple enough function you might actually be able calculate the fitness of the children even without explicitly generating them and then only generate them if its worth while.

Answer (score 0):

Addenda to previous comments: pruning can also be done at multiple levels, depending on your performance and memory constraints. For example:

1. Put the initial state into a priority queue.
2. Until termination (e.g. queue is empty, adequate solution found, time limit expired, ...), repeat the following:

   2.1. Take the top entry from the queue.

   2.2. Generate its children (using an estimator to get highest-value children first, if possible).

   2.3. As each child is generated, put it into the priority queue. Once the queue reaches a size limit (which you probably determine empirically by trial and error), each insertion into the queue should be accompanied by deletion of the lowest-value element in the queue.

Obviously, having good estimating/evaluating functions is important to making this work. Your queue evaluation function can be tweaked to take "generation" into account (e.g. giving a weighted bonus to states nearer the initial state, at shallower depth) to tune its bias between depth-preferences and breadth-preference.

Comment: 1)The childern that i want to generate are any state that can be reached from the parent by making one move(ex:Swap between 2 lectures)
2)Priority queue is very nice idea but its performance wont be good because i am thinking to generate the whole space in the first time,give each node a value,get the best and update the values according to my selection.So i have to get the max from the array of node O(n),and then update the necessary information.Due to the fact that i have huge amount of possiibilities and i want to go deep in search,this will make performance not as i hope.Can i manage it?

Comment: To search all possible states, you need either a VERY constrained universe or VERY large amounts of memory. Most realistic scheduling problems are too large for exhaustive search. The priority-queue approach is based on the assumption that you want the best result achievable within some boundaries (time spent searching, number of cases to check, memory available for combinations to explore, etc.) You can constrain the search space further by setting a threshold on queued states. Evaluate "goodness" and queue a newly-produced state only if it achieves some minimum quality.

Answer (score 0):

“Timetable scheduler” sounds like a scheduling problem or constraint satisfaction problem (CSP) will probably be the best approach